# preg_replace keep : \

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to use regular expressions to work on some strings.

At the moment i'm using this expression `$var1=trim(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\']/', ' ', $myString));`
But with this one i'm loosing some characters i want to keep.
Those characters are '.' '\' and ':'. Can someone give me some hints to maintain those characters? Thanks for your time

UPDATE 
Using Adlan string i got the right result. Now i have another problem but is not inerent with the topic. Anyway i get this string after preg_repleace `Found some changes in D:\EER Data\project\myfile.csv` 
In this string there are correct backslashes but when i call json_encode($myString) backslashes are gone..

**UPDATE2**
OK , i found the problem and i know how to solve it.
I have to put double \ where there is only a .
So this string `D:\EER Data\project\myfile.csv` should become `D:\\EER Data\\project\\myfile.csv`
How can i achieve this with preg_replace? Thanks for the help

Comment: right now you're replacing anything that is _not_ A-Z a-z 0-9, - and '. You want it the other way round, right?

Comment: Please add an example of `$myString`, and what output you expect.

Comment: Ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use:

```
/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\'\\\.\:]/
```

Answer (score 0):

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/UmUbE))

```
$myString=<<<TEXT
Found some changes in D:\EER Data\project\myfile.csv
TEXT;

$var1=trim(preg_replace("~[^a-z\d.:'\\\-]~i", ' ', $myString));  // keep letters, numbers dot, colon, single-quote, backslash, and hyphen

echo "$var1\n";

echo json_encode($var1);  // it's a good idea to keep the escaping \ while in json.
```

Output:

```
Found some changes in D:\EER Data\project\myfile.csv
"Found some changes in D:\\EER Data\\project\\myfile.csv"
```